# Delaying execution of page scripts until the extension completes asynchronous initialization through content scripts

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-chrome-extension, chromium, microsoft-edge-chromium

Is it possible to delay or stop the loading, parsing, and execution of web page JavaScripts until the extension fetches the saved settings from `chrome.storage` and performs initial setup?

Even though, the `content script` is set to `"run_at": "document_start"`, because of the asynchronous nature of the `chrome.storage` read, while the stored configuration settings are being read using `chrome.storage.local.get()`, it appears that the web page also starts parsing and executing the page scripts simultaneously.

However, the extension wants to perform some initial configuration *by running some content scripts* based upon previously saved settings, hence the need for a way to pause or delay the execution of the scripts until the initial setup is complete which also injects a content script to the page which is supposed to be fully executed before the page scripts.

***Note - This question is strictly about delaying or pausing the execution of the web page's scripts,
and it is already set to "run_at": "document_start". Currently using manifest v2, but solution for either v2 or v3 is fine. ***